# MYSQL Stored Procedure Query Fallback Logic

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, database-design, mysql-logic

I am sure this is a stupid question but after reading everything I cannot figure out the proper way of creating a stored procedure with fallback logic for the Where clause.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT FeeName, Amount, Category, VariableName 
FROM client_rates WHERE state_abv = state_abvIN 
AND Purchase= purchaseIN AND Category= CategoryIN And client_id=client_idIN AND
agent_id=agent_idIN AND ((lender_id=lender_idIN AND county=countyIN) OR (lender_id=lender_idIN
AND
county='NA') OR (lender_id=1 AND county=countyIN) OR (lender_id=1 AND county='NA'));
```

Because I have used OR it will return a set which matches all 4 conditions. What I want is to "fallback" through conditions.

Meaning I want it to return a set where (lender_id=lender_idIN AND county=countyIN) returns a value. However if it returns a NULL set then try the next condition set (lender_id=lender_idIN AND county='NA') and etc.

I dont think CASE will work for this issue and I once used nested IF EXIST statements which worked but forced each query to run twice (there has to be a better solution than that).

Any suggestions and thank you for the help.

Comment: Trying to use COALESCE now. Ok, it looks like it worked and is the correct solution. If there are any better options or potential pitfalls with this solution I am all ears.

Comment: Actually Coalesce is not the answer.... Still looking. Would love the help

Comment: Found a FOUND_ROW() method that I can check for greater than 0 and then follow if logic.

Comment: By "matches all 4" you probably mean "matches one or more of 4"? And by "NULL set" you probably mean "empty table", ie "table with no rows"? And by "condition set" you probably mean "condition" (here one that is a "disjunct")? Also, the rest of your description ("Meaning...") is not clear. Try using enough words to describe the rows you want rather than a procedure to go through. PS If you have to put "fallback" in quotes and give a definition, why use it at all, especially in the title?

Comment: Except that you probably mean "if there's a match for lender_id & county, return them, otherwise if there's a match for lender_id return it & 'NA' for county, otherwise if there's a match for county return it & 1 for lender_id, otherwise return 1 & 'NA'"? If you had something "which worked" then put it into your question to explain what you want.

Comment: Thanks for help @philipxy, I thought the description made sense but I can see the confusion. And your second comment is exactly what my question was meant to ask. I thought "fallback would have been a good explanation. Also is it incorrect terminology to say a query returns an empty set?

Comment: 1. Although "fallback" is a good vague description, it's not an *explanation*. Will anyone search for it? 2. "Returns an empty set" is ok and will be understood. But really it returns an empty table holding an empty set; an SQL table also has a heading/schema of columns even when empty. Most database relations in research papers are ust sets but they are usually paired with schemas. (Why not post that question?)

Comment: My "Except..." comment was not meant to describe what my answer describes! See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I'll assume that the ...IN symbols are parameters not columns, that 'NA' is a possible value for county in client_rates, and that in your WHERE's last AND condition you want to return rows where (...), otherwise where (...), otherwise where (...), etc. (A CASE expression evaluates only up to the first true WHEN.)

```
SELECT FeeName, Amount, Category, VariableName 
FROM client_rates
WHERE state_abv=state_abvIN 
AND Purchase=purchaseIN AND Category=CategoryIN
AND client_id=client_idIN AND agent_id=agent_idIN
AND CASE WHEN (lender_id=lender_idIN AND county=countyIN) THEN 1
    WHEN (lender_id=lender_idIN AND county='NA') THEN 1
    WHEN (lender_id=1 AND county=countyIN) THEN 1
    ELSE (lender_id=1 AND county='NA')
    END;
```

PS:
But that is a *different* query from the following: When there is a match for everything before the CASE, if lender_idIN is not found then 1 is returned for lender_id (whether or not there is a lender_id=1) and if countyIN is not found then 'NA' is returned for county (whether or not there is a county='NA'). (This probably involves 'NA' not being a possible value for county in client_rates.) When they give different results: If lender_idIN is not found but there is no client_rates lender_id value of 1 and/or if countyIN is not found but there is no client_rates county value of 'NA'. Then the first query will return an empty table but the second query returns a 1 for lender_id and/or a 'NA' for county. Make your "Meaning..." clear! Include the query "which worked" (if you're sure it did).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try to be more clear with any new questions.